# Getting numbers from within a string

Tags: java, string

I am writing a Java hangman game where the user enters a letter guess and then guesses in which spaces the letter is in. For easy mode, the user can guess 4 spaces. The user must guess 4 spaces with a space between the numbers.

My question is, I have `String guesses = keyboard.next();` but the issue I am having issue with is, how can I get the number that's at index `0`, `2`, `4`, and `6`? I am not allowed to use `int space1 = keyboard.nextInt();` and so on. I have to use a string. So how can I extract the numbers at indices `0`, `2`, `4`, and `6` from the string guesses?

P.S. I am not allowed to use arrays or the string builder class.

Comment: Have a look at `String.substring` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Did you try anything? You wil have a much better chance of getting useful answers if you can provide some code that you have tried, together with a few comments on what isn't working.

Comment: Also, the code you gave would make more sense if you included some context.

Comment: HI Keppil, I would post some code but I am not allowed to post my code online per my class academic honesty policy. I have done quite a bit of research, but what I've found uses stuff I have not yet learned. Also, please don't post if it's not helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You're not allowed to share the code, but you can ask strangers to do the work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming for example

```
String s = "xx3x";

int j = s.charAt(2) - '0';
```

This gives j == 3.